# PHP Fatal error in string function

Tags: php, string

I got this error in PHP:

> Fatal error:  Function name must be a string

I don't know why... Here's my code:

```
$string = function($airport, $return) { blabla return something; }
```

And in a function I call this by:

```
$string2 = $string("EGLL", "raw");
```

and this generates an error.

Comment: Which php version are you using? Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Version 5.5.9, Safari, Mac OSX

Comment: i should be like his form <?php

function maximum($x, $y) {
    if ($x > $y) return $x;
    else return $y;
}

$a = 23;
$b = 32;

$val = maximum($a, $b);
echo "The max of $a, $b is $val \n";

?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scoping problem. You say "in just a function," which I take to mean "inside another function."

This code will work, because you both define and use `$string` in the global scope:

```
$string = function($airport, $return) { echo $airport , ', ', $return; };    
$string2 = $string("EGLL", "raw");
```

But this will not:

```
$string = function($airport, $return) { echo $airport , ', ', $return; };

function foo() {
    $string2 = $string("EGLL", "raw");
}

foo();
```

It fails because there is no variable `$string` inside the function `foo`. It's like calling `null("EGLL", "raw")`, which is invalid.

You need to use the `global` keyword:

```
$string = function($airport, $return) { echo $airport , ', ', $return; };

function foo() {
    global $string; // add this line
    $string2 = $string("EGLL", "raw");
}

foo();
```

**Note that this is *not* necessarily good practice**; that depends on what you're really trying to do.

Also note that you need the `;` after your function definition to avoid syntax errors.